# Polymer layout with dynamic width according to screen size

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I come from a Bootstrap background, where I'm very used to laying out `<div>` elements with a grid value for the number of columns I want that div to occupy, with the freedom to set different values for different screen sizes.
Lets say that for a certain `div` I want to add the following classes: `col-md-6 col-xs-12`. How can I achieve a similar result using Polymer?

So far I've read through the `iron-flex-layout` documentation page, and after several unsuccessful attempts I think it's really not designed for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

iron-flex-layout is really just a bunch of helper classes and mixins for flexbox. What you're trying to do can definitely be accomplished with flexbox, but you'll need to understand how it works first (not entirely trivial).

There seems to be a third party grid layout component for Polymer though that does exactly what you are looking for: https://github.com/The5heepDev/iron-grid